# How do I redirect URL based on its filepath?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I need to redirect all traffic based on the start of a URL, including the domain name and a bit of the filepath:

So that

http://www.mywebsite.co.uk/home/this/path/stays/thesame/ & http://mywebsite.co.uk/home/this/path/stays/thesame/

become

http://minigame.mywebsite.co.uk/home/this/path/stays/thesame

So as you can see the redirect is only invoked when the url is pointing to the /home/ directory.

I have no experience with writing .htaccess files beyond copy and paste, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This solution doesn't use the .htaccess technique but will still offer you the functionality.
The only disadvantage doing it this way that I know of is that you have to add the code to the pages that you would like the redirect to happen on.

This works best if you have a template based system and can apply this to one file and it will automatically adjust to suit each page.

```
$path = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];                  // Path after domain
$newdomain = 'http://minigame.mywebsite.co.uk'    // New domain for redirect
header("Location: $newdomain.$path")              // Redirect user to new location
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your **`/home/.htaccess`** file of old website:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?mywebsite\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://mywebsite.co.uk%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=302]
```